# Weighted MATLAB Fit Cftools

Tags: matlab

Excuse my post if this is too basic of a question. Complete newbie here. So I want to preform a weighted fit of some data points given one array that holds the data points and another that holds the weights. I've followed the instructions [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/interactive-curve-and-surface-fitting-.html) up until now, but the fit I'm generating seems to give more weight to the points with a greater weight and less to points with lesser weight, but my weights are standard deviations and I want to give more weight to points with a smaller standard deviation.

**Question: How can I change the default weighting procedure to give more weight to data points with smaller weight values (e.g. standard deviations)**

Comment: Lets say your array with the standard deviations is called `array_std`. Then you can just pass the inverse as weights: `1./array_std`; this should give you what you want.